# handle incoming calls from browser

Tags: mobile, voip, sip, telephony

How to handle incoming calls (from Land Line / Mobile ) to browser ? that means a client can handle all his incoming calls via browser only they no need to go to fetch their phones at the time of working

Just like Twilio handles all incoming calls in their OpenVBX client

After searching  few things i came to know following ( i may wrong so please do help in getting better)

- It needs some Virtual Number so that a person can dial this number
- It requires some kind of hardware which converts PSTN line to VOIP (may be ATA adapter)

What i want to know is ?

- how can one implement the handling of incoming call from PSTN line or mobile
- Does this require any sort of hardware setups
- How one can get their own Virtual Number (Free or Setup Our Own - dont want it from skype or google voice and other paid services)
- Does this require any further setups

you can say i want to develop  a kind of softphone in which i can only handle incoming calls

Comment: Please read the answers from this  [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355923/a-little-explanation-in-understanding-how-sip-webrtc-and-pstn-work-together/23020779?noredirect=1#23020779

Answer (score 1):

Most of your questions about where to get a number, the hardware required for VoIP etc aren't programming related. If the [Telephony](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12932/telephony) site ever gets off the ground it would be the place to ask those sort of questions. There are lots of VoIP providers that can provide you with incoming DIDs and every other kind of VoIP/PSTN integration service you could want.

As far as handling calls in a browser there are lots of different options, here are three to get you started:

- You could set up your own Asterisk/FreeSWTICH or other soft switch and do some kind of HTTP integration in your dialplan that would notify a browser about call events,
- You could take a look at [phono](http://phono.com/) from voxeo which is a javascript API that talks to back end SIP servers,
- Or you could run a SIP stack directly in a browser or as I've done with my [Silverlight switchboard](https://www.sipsorcery.com/mainsite/Help/SwitchboardGettingStarted) which provides notifications and call handling abilities within a browser with SIP

Comment: As far Silverlight Switchboard is concerned , does it capable of handling PSTN and mobile incoming calls also ?

Comment: It is capable of handling them but the calls have to be transferred from the PSTN to the Internet beforehand. That's where VoIP Providers come in, they act as the gateways between the PSTN and the internet.